# how to boot uImage of arm 64 bit kernel on raspberrypi 3?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, raspberry-pi3

I build the linux kernel-4.6 for rpi3 and tried to boot it up from u-boot using the following commands.

In u-boot console

`fatload mmc 0:1 $fdt_addr_r bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
fatload mmc 0:1 $loadaddr Image
setenv bootargs root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=tty0 rootfstype=ext4
booti $loadaddr - $fdt_addr_r`

All the binaries are in place and the kernel just boots fine.

`$loadaddr` is `0x00200000`
`$fdt_addr_r` is `0x00000100`

How can I boot the uImage of the kernel instead of the Image binary since I don't know much about the type of Image binary (which shows up as MS Dos executable on doing `file Image`)

**My Failed Attempt**

Using the `mkimage` utility, I created the uImage as follows and then tried to boot it up using the following commands.

`./mkimage -A arm64 -O Linux -T kernel -C none -a 0x80080000 -e 0x80080000 -d Image uImage`

In u-boot console

`fatload mmc 0:1 $fdt_addr_r bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
fatload mmc 0:1 $loadaddr uImage
setenv bootargs root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=AMA0
bootm $loadaddr - $fdt_addr_r`

But nothing happens and u-boot binary gets rebooted itself. Can `bootm` be used to boot the uImage of arm 64 bit kernel? Or the uImage created is itself not correct? What am I missing?

Comment: What is the actual address for the start of physical memory?  Seems like it's 0x0, according to the U-Boot commands that you say work.  Is there that much installed RAM that the kernel should be loaded at 0x80080000?  Where are these addresses coming from?

Comment: I was not sure of the addresses so tried creating uImage with different addresses. Tried 0x0020000 and also 0x01000000 but does't work and the Image binary gets loaded at these addresses and works fine!!

Comment: First, please provide the whole of the console log from U-Boot, in both cases.  And second, note that you don't need to use a uImage here, just keep booting the Image file, it doesn't matter what 'file' thinks that it is.  If you must wrap the Image file, try making a FIT image instead.  Not that uImage shouldn't work (it works on other arm64 platforms) but it's been long deprecated.